What are these? Old Printing Positives on Glass?
I recently came into the possession of many of these glass "things." I believe they're glass positives used for offset printing, but I'd love to learn more. Heck, I'd like to know that I'm wrong, and educate myself.
I have them in many sizes: 18" x 18" up to 24" x 36". They are very heavy. I've only looked at a few. I would date them from 1940 - 1970, and maybe older.
Once I figure out what they are, I'll explore what to do with them.
Thanks.


Those are certainly positives used for making printing negatives using a light sensitive coating/material.
Most likely for offset printing, but possibly also for silk screen printing. If they were for color offset printing I would expect there to multiples with variations for each color.

I have found examples where multiple colors were identified for the same image. They did not identify with CMYK though. They seem to be spot colors.
